# Eigen: Accessing ProductBase coefficients

Tags: c++, eigen

The following code snippet dies from an Eigen assert:

```
MatrixXd L;
VectorXd x, b;
...
ASSERT_MATRIX_EQ(L*x, b);
```

With,

```
template <typename DerivedL, typename DerivedR>
void ASSERT_MATRIX_EQ(const Eigen::DenseBase<DerivedL>& A, const Eigen::DenseBase<DerivedR>& B, double tol=1e-7) {
    ASSERT_EQ(A.rows(), B.rows());
    ASSERT_EQ(A.cols(), B.cols());
    for(int i=0; i < A.rows(); i++) {
        for(int j=0; j < A.cols(); j++) {
            ASSERT_NEAR(A(i,j), B(i,j), tol);
        }
    }
}
```

It dies with the error:

```
test_leq: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/ProductBase.h:154: typename Base::CoeffReturnType Eigen::ProductBase<Eigen::GeneralProduct<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >::coeff(Index, Index) const: Assertion `this->rows() == 1 && this->cols() == 1' failed.
```

in the call to `A(i,j)`. (However, I can call `cout << A << endl;` just fine.)

On line 154, `ProductBase.h` curiously has the assertion

```
    // restrict coeff accessors to 1x1 expressions. No need to care about mutators here since this isnt a Lvalue expression
    typename Base::CoeffReturnType coeff(Index row, Index col) const
    {
#ifdef EIGEN2_SUPPORT
      return lhs().row(row).cwiseProduct(rhs().col(col).transpose()).sum();
#else
      EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT_SIZE_1x1(Derived)
      eigen_assert(this->rows() == 1 && this->cols() == 1);
      return derived().coeff(row,col);
#endif
    }
```

I'm following [Eigen's guide](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html) for writing generic matrix functions. How do I write this generic function correctly?

Edit: It would also be nice to know why `ProductBase` expects a 1x1 matrix.

Answer (score 1):

A [thread](http://listengine.tuxfamily.org/lists.tuxfamily.org/eigen/2010/06/msg00014.html) on the Eigen mailing list indicates that coefficient access on a `ProductBase` is intentionally disabled. The solution for now is to just avoid expressions like `foobar(A*x)`.